# Ordenar un array

Tags: php

Tengo este Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 2017<br>Condenser<br>Buick Verano
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [description] => COMPLETE COOLING (RAD/CON/FAN)
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [part_grade] => A
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [stock] => AA0818
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [us_price] => $450
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [dealer_info] => Auto Alex USA-CA(Sun-Valley)  Request_Quote 818-504-7600 Request_Insurance_Quote

                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [dist_mile] => 2344
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 2013<br>Condenser<br>Cadillac XTS
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [description] => WTH RAD AND FAN ASSM,8-12,000-44K
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [part_grade] => A
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [stock] => 217563
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [us_price] => $400.01
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [dealer_info] => Miami Parts USA-FL(Opa-Locka)  Request_Quote 1-800-644-4788 Request_Insurance_Quote

                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [dist_mile] => 9
                )

        )
```

Pero este no me sirve y quisiera convertirlo como el siguiente, lo he intentado ya y no lo consigo, me gustaria dejarlo de este modo.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (

                    [data] => 2017<br>Condenser<br>Buick Verano,
                    [description] => COMPLETE COOLING (RAD/CON/FAN),
                    [part_grade] => A,
                    [stock] => AA0818,
                    [us_price] => $450,
                    [dealer_info] => Auto Alex USA-CA(Sun-Valley)  Request_Quote 818-504-7600 Request_Insurance_Quote
,
                    [dist_mile] => 2344

        )

    [1] => Array
        (

                    [data] => 2013<br>Condenser<br>Cadillac XTS,
                    [description] => WTH RAD AND FAN ASSM,8-12,000-44K,
                    [part_grade] => A,
                    [stock] => 217563,
                    [us_price] => $400.01,
                    [dealer_info] => Miami Parts USA-FL(Opa-Locka)  Request_Quote 1-800-644-4788 Request_Insurance_Quote
,
                    [dist_mile] => 9       


        )
```

Aqui esta el codigo de la funcion que genera el array

```
public function getResults(Request $request)
{

    $params = array(
        "userDate" => $request->userDate, 
        "userModel" => $request->userModel,
        "userPart" => $request->userPart,
        "userLocation" => $request->userLocation,
        "userPreference" => $request->userPreference,
        "userZip" => $request->userZip,
        "userVIN" => "",
        "svZip" => "y",
        "userPage" => "1",
        "userInterchange" => $request->userInterchange,
        "userDate2" => "Ending Year",
        "userSearch" => "int",
        "Search Car Part Inventory.x" => "33",
        "Search Car Part Inventory.y" => "10",
    );

    // Send a GET request to: http://www.foo.com/bar
    $response = Curl::to('http://car-part.com/cgi-bin/search.cgi')
    ->withContentType('application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    ->withData($params)
    ->post();

    if(stripos($response, "dummyVar")) {
        echo "contiene";
    } else {
        if (stripos($response, "dbPart") && stripos($response, "userInterchange=")) {
            $index = stripos($response, "<table width=\"100%\" border=\"1\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"4\">");
            $response = substr($response, $index);
            $index = stripos($response, "</table>");
            $response = substr($response, 0, $index + 8);
            $index = stripos($response, "</tr>");
            $response = substr($response, $index + 5);
            $index = strripos($response, "<tr>");
            $response = substr($response, 0, $index);
            $response = str_replace("<tr>", "", $response);
            $response = str_replace("<td>", "", $response);
            $response = str_replace("<td align=center>", "", $response);
            $response = str_replace("<td align=center nowrap>", "", $response);

            $response = explode("</tr>", $response);

            $temp = array();

            foreach ($response as $key => $value) {
                # code...
                $value = explode("</td>", $value);
                array_pop($value);
                array_push($temp, $value);

            }

           $response = array();

           for ($i=0; $i < count($temp); $i++) { 
                $arr = array();
                $labels = ['data', 'description', 'part_grade', 'stock', 'us_price', 'dealer_info', 'dist_mile'];
               # code...


                for ($j=0; $j < count($temp[$i]); $j++) { 
                    # code...

                    array_push($arr, [$labels[$j] => $temp[$i][$j]]);

                }
                array_push($response, $arr);

           }
           print_r($response);



        } else {
             return response()->json(['statusCode' => 404, 'statusText' => "Not Found", 'data' => null], 404);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: se te forma solo ese array o lo formas tu en algun for ?.

Comment: Puedes agregar el código donde generas esos arrays? Para poder ayudarte de mejor forma.

Comment: Listo, ya edite la respuesta y anadi el codigo

Comment: ¿`$response` es el array resultante? ¿Qué hay, o mejor dicho, cómo queda `$temp` después de llenarlo? No logro ver su estructura, porque no sé qué llegó desde el `Curl`...

Comment: Si tienes acceso al código que crea el array en sí quizá puedas construirlo como quieres en el origen... sería la forma óptima de hacerlo. Confirma si es posible tener acceso a ese código.

Comment: $response es el array que tengo resultante, y lo quiero convertir en el de abajo, como agruparlo

Comment: Desde curl llega una tabla en HTML en la cual hago varios cambios para obtener los datos de la tabla en servidor y devolverlos como JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione de este modo

```
$response = array();
array_pop($temp);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($temp); $i++) {
    $arr = array(
        'data' => $temp[$i][0],
        'description' => $temp[$i][1],
        'part_grade' => $temp[$i][2],
        'stock' => $temp[$i][3],
        'us_price' => $temp[$i][4],
        'dealer_info' => $temp[$i][5],
        'dist_mile' => $temp[$i][6],
    );
    array_push($response, $arr);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes de cambiar el formato de tus loops anidados asi:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($temp); $i++) { 
    $arr = array();
    $labels = ['data', 'description', 'part_grade', 'stock', 'us_price', 'dealer_info', 'dist_mile'];
           # code...


    for ($j=0; $j < count($temp[$i]); $j++) { 
                # code...

        $arr[$labels[$j] = $temp[$i][$j]]);

    }
    array_push($response, $arr);

}
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, sin embargo, ya encontre la solucion.

Answer (score 0):

Esta función te podría servir.

Usa  **[`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php)** para crear un nuevo array sin tener que preocuparte de cuáles valores tengan las claves.

```
/*Función que llamará array_map*/

function mapByIndex( $array ) {
    $arr=array();
    foreach ( $array as $v ){
        if ( is_array( $v ) ) {
            foreach ( $v as $key => $value ) {
                $arr[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}

/*Enviamos el array original, para que lo ordene*/   
$arrNew = array_map( "mapByIndex", $arrOriginal );
```

Si hacemos una prueba:

```
print_r( $arrNew );
```

Tendremos el resultado siguiente:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2017<br>Condenser<br>Buick Verano
            [description] => COMPLETE COOLING (RAD/CON/FAN)
            [part_grade] => A
            [stock] => AA0818
            [us_price] => $450
            [dealer_info] => Auto Alex USA-CA(Sun-Valley)  Request_Quote 818-504-7600 Request_Insurance_Quote
            [dist_mile] => 2344
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [data] => 2013<br>Condenser<br>Cadillac XTS
            [description] => WTH RAD AND FAN ASSM,8-12,000-44K
            [part_grade] => A
            [stock] => 217563
            [us_price] => $400.01
            [dealer_info] => Miami Parts USA-FL(Opa-Locka)  Request_Quote 1-800-644-4788 Request_Insurance_Quote
            [dist_mile] => 9
        )

)
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

---

#### Demo

<kbd>**[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/UFXAG49893)**</kbd>

Comment: Excelente informacion